# Save password in preferences under "Accounts & Passwords"

Tags: swift, autofill, ios11, wwdc

At WWDC Apple presented the AutoFill feature for iOS Apps in a [presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206/). It is fairly simple to set up and works really well. If the user entered a password in safari and saved it. However, if the user never used Safari, but only the app, currently the user still has to type out the password every time.

I am already storing the password in the keychain. Unfortunately this does not put the password in the settings below "**Accounts & Passwords > App & Website Passwords**". Is there any way, how I can store the password the user entered into my app to this settings page, so that the user gets a suggestion for it, when logging in the next time?

Comment: This could be an oversight by Apple. It seems as though if there is an associated domain it should be able to pop-up the "Save Password?" dialog that you see in Safari when you log in to a new website. I would suggest [filing a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Safari Credential in your app and it will show up in `Accounts & Passwords > App & Website Passwords`. This username/password will then be an autofill option.

See the docs on [SecAddSharedWebCredential](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials).