# How to save Passwords on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When googling this, many articles say "Save to KeyChain".

I have given this a go and it works well. But I am looking to save the password so that it saves to

`Settings -> Passwords & Accounts`

[image]

I've googled a ton and many articles say to Save to KeyChain, even with my keychain implementation, it doesn't appear. KeyChain looks to be a secure, local storage. So I'm wondering is there another way or is it called something else? Any tips or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Save password in preferences under “Accounts & Passwords”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965589/save-password-in-preferences-under-accounts-passwords)?

Comment: @Daniel that's swift, this is xamarin. BUT there could be similarities.

Comment: @Phoenix 1) Is iCloud enabled on that device (thus the iCloud KeyChain)? 2) Are you using the Security framework?

Comment: @SushiHangover ICloud is enabled, I am able to save a password directly to that location via starbucks app. I believe I am. I'm adding new keys using `SecKeyChain.Add(new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword){ ... }`.  I hope that's the right approach but I am not entirely sure.